# onResumeFragments can't be overridden?

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to use the same code as given in Facebook's Android SDK's official tutorial [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/). I also managed to make the tutorial app. However, now I need the exactly similar code in my another app. However, this time, Eclipse says that the `onResumeFragments()` method given in code can't be overridden and if I comment out the `@Override` notation and `super.onResumeFragments()`, and try to run the project, my app shows a blank activity..
Here is the code I run..

```
package com.gotechno.technovanza13;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;


public class FbLoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int SPLASH = 0;
    private static final int SELECTION = 1;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SELECTION +1;
    private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];
    private boolean isResumed = false;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
        new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fb_fragment_container);

        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragments[SPLASH] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
        fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            if (i == fragmentIndex) {
                transaction.show(fragments[i]);
            } else {
                transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
            }
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception     exception) {
        // Only make changes if the activity is visible
        if (isResumed) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            // Get the number of entries in the back stack
            int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            // Clear the back stack
            for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
                manager.popBackStack();
            }
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                // If the session state is open:
                // Show the authenticated fragment
                showFragment(SELECTION, false);
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                // If the session state is closed:
                // Show the login fragment
                showFragment(SPLASH, false);
            }
        }
    }

    //@Override <--- here is where I commented out to remove error
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        //super.onResumeFragments();   <--- here is where I commented out to remove error
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // if the session is already open,
            // try to show the selection fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else {
            // otherwise present the splash screen
            // and ask the person to login.
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Please tell how to override the method correctly and load the fragment activity...thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you're trying to use an older version of the library. If you look at the [history](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=fragmentactivity), it was only added on 4.1.1 .

Comment: Thanks, any ways to get through it, then?

Answer (score 0):

I had removed the 'android-support-v4.jar' earlier from my project's `lib` because I had encountered JAR mismatch. Addint the file again solved my problem.. :)